# Does the sqlite-net async API support dispose?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I'm using the sqlite-net async API to code a Windows Phone app. While writing a unit test to make sure that my adapter to the sqlite-net API created the file properly, I noticed that the adapter continues holding onto the file handle even after it has gone out of scope.

The async connection class (`SQLiteAsyncConnection`) does not support `IDisposable` so I cannot manually dispose it. Looking at the source, it seems like the async API creates a connection, uses it and disposes it every time. However, when my test cleanup code attempts to delete the created test database, some other resource is still holding onto it.

Comment: If that was the case perhaps you just need to call GC.Collect() before trying to delete. However, I'm not seeing this behavior myself. :-(

Comment: More than ten years ago they already knew NOT to call GC.Collect() manually http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2003/12/02/two-things-to-avoid-for-better-memory-usage.aspx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem in case where database was supposed to be sent via email for debugging/analyzing purposes. There was no way of doing that because connection is held.

You can go around this by modifying the sqlite-net implementation a bit.

On top of `SQLiteAsync.cs` add following partial class declaration.

```
namespace SQLite
{
    public partial class SQLiteAsyncConnection
    {
        public void ResetConnections()
        {
            SQLiteConnectionPool.Shared.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

and then change access modifier of above `Reset` method as `public`.

In your application code just call `<YourSQLiteAsyncConnection>.ResetConnections();` before deleting the DB file.

---

Then again, when testing you could create your database in memory so you don't have to delete it at all. You can achieve this by setting DatabasePath as `":memory:"`.

Answer (score 2):

[On November 23rd 2015 they added a static method](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/commit/6c59e40d63afb52c4836d97163237fac8cf8311b) that does what Mikko Viitala suggested, So I just put the following in my dispose method.

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection.ResetPool();
```